# Quotes in market basket analysis in R

Tags: r, apriori, market-basket-analysis

I am trying to do a priori analysis in R, but since I will run this in different environment, I have to do this without "read.transactions" function (because this one requires taking data from a file, which I can't do in this example). In other words - I have to operate with columns that I already have, without relating to any file.
So, here is an example I wrote to show You my problem:

```
test <- data.frame(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), c("1, 2, 3", "2, 4", "1, 5, 2", "4, 1", "2, 3, 4, 5"))
colnames(test) <- c("TransactionID", "items")
test$TransactionID <- as.factor(test$TransactionID)
rules <- as(split(as.vector(test[,2]),as.vector(test[,1])), "transactions")
tkoszyk <- apriori(rules, parameter=list(minlen=2, sup=0.1, conf=0.1, target="rules"))
inspect(tkoszyk)
```

So the problem here is that this function reads my item vector in a wrong way. This is an output:

```
    lhs    rhs          support confidence lift count
[1] {}  => {1, 2, 3}    0.2     0.2        1    1    
[2] {}  => {2, 4}       0.2     0.2        1    1    
[3] {}  => {1, 5, 2}    0.2     0.2        1    1    
[4] {}  => {4, 1}       0.2     0.2        1    1    
[5] {}  => {2, 3, 4, 5} 0.2     0.2        1    1
```

So basically what it does is that instead of making itemlist like that:

```
"1" "2" "3" "4" "5"
```

it makes itemlist like that:

```
"1, 2, 3"    "1, 5, 2"    "2, 3, 4, 5" "2, 4"       "4, 1"
```

During my investigation in this topic I learned that a problem here is with **quotes**. Just for trying I made this example in R with using 'read.transactions' and when I marked 'quote' argument as FALSE, it started work properly. But one more time, since I can not use read.transactions. I do not know how to deal with this problem.
Of course this data is only an example, so in my real data, I can not change it that easily, I have to do it using some R code, without using files.
I think the best idea I had was some trying with

```
capture.output(cat(test$items))
```

But still I can't make it work.
Would appreciate any help, I am pretty hopeless already.

Comment: Ok, so I discovered that the thing here is probably about 'single' or 'basket' format of file. But still, using "as" function does not let me change format from single to basket

Answer (score 0):

Your splitting does not work. You should do something like:

```
itemList <- strsplit(as.character(test$items), split = ", ")
trans <- as(itemList, "transactions")
inspect(trans)

    items    
[1] {1,2,3}  
[2] {2,4}    
[3] {1,2,5}  
[4] {1,4}    
[5] {2,3,4,5}
```